# When we type an address in search bar, in some web mapping applications like google maps, a list of words automatically displayed from the database.

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, web-mapping

What is actually happening behind the code and how should be the code? 
when we search for a specifc word, will it look in the database (here it is postGIS) and lists the similar words.

Comment: The process you are referring to is commonly known as 'autocomplete'

Comment: Possible answer depending on what you're trying to do: [Find n Nearest Neighbors for given Point using PostGIS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5111843/386205)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are talking about is called 'autocomplete'. Google Maps API has the 'Places Library' which provides some of the functionality you are asking about. [Read more about that here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) However if you are planning on implementing your own using your own database then it is a much more extensive process. A good place for you to start is [this guide](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/dlarochelle/2010/12/27/using-postgresql-for-an-ajax-autocomplete-field/) and also there is always [stackexchange questions tagged with autocomplete.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autocomplete)